# Can't wait for thread conclusion inside onPause

Tags: android, multithreading, onpause

I need to destroy a thread before application suspend. This is my code:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
   public boolean mRun = false;;
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
        while (mRun)
        {
              .....
        }
    }
 }
```

Activity:

```
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
    if (mThread != null)
    {       
        mThread.mRun = false;           
        try { mThread.join(); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

But i'm pretty sure that the android system do not wait my thread conclusion and pause my application before it. How can i force thread conclusion?

Comment: don't catch exceptions without at least logging it. anyway, you cannot make the user wait for a thread to potentially terminate before doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way, I used in my code meet your requirement.Hope, this will be helping you too. If you find a better solution, Please share it.

In the below snippet, `mThread` is thread got created in `onCreate`. `OnDestroy` is a method that would be called before your activity destroyed.Its a best place to empty the allocated resources.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(null != mThread) {
        Thread dummyThread = mThread;
        mThread = null;
        dummyThread.interrupt(); // Post an interrupt request to this thread.
       }
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: please note that the interrupt request doesn't do much in itself unless the thread is in a wait() or in a blocking I/O

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not getting an InterruptedException?
Try putting a stacktrace in the catch sentence...and also check if your thread isAlive().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Thread.join is a blocking potentially long operation that must not be done on the UI Thread (onPause being on the UI Thread).

You can ask your thread to stop, (setting mRun to false is a commonly accepted way of doing so), but you cannot exclicitely wait on it.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure , mark the thread as daemon, always check a flag if doing a repetitive task in a thread, like in a loop. Also, call interrupt, which will take care of blocking IO or network calls.

```
myThread.setDaemon(true)
```

and

```
cancelFlag = true;
myThread.interrupt();
```